# CouchDB optimal document model for Geo data

Tags: json, couchdb

Start building a webapp that shows several places in a city.
But before that trying building a good database modelling foundation in CouchDB.

So, every **city** is a document and has different **places** in town. The **email**, is the person that send/adding the place. The **comments** are for extra info at the place.
Try working hierarchical.

Next step is showing all the places on a Leaflet-map and filter by 'city'.

```
 - city
  - place 1
  - place 2
  - ...
  - place x
```

Here my document model:

```
{
"_id": "52888cacec450d22e4baa0c1754cb777",
"_rev": "2-c916a9d3ce0a86a775dd232996c0f865",
"zip": "8660",
"city": "Adinkerke",
"province": "West-Vlaanderen",
"lng": 2.5896028375712,
"lat": 51.06926315,
"comments": "",
"locations": [
  {
   "places": "1",
   "lat": "51.074319",
   "lng": "2.599509",
   "street": "Kerkweg",
   "comments": "",
   "email": "c***@gmail.com",
   "published": "27/12/2019"
  },
  {
   "places": "1",
   "lat": "51.075027",
   "lng": " 2.602127",
   "street": "Dorpstraat",
   "comments": "Parking Dorpstraat/Kerkweg",
   "email": "c***@gmail.com",
   "published": "27/12/2019"
  }
 ]
}
```

Some advice, if it can better or not?

Answer (score 0):

Flip your model inside out instead -- let each location be a separate document which has a "city" field, and then use a map keyed on "city" to get all locations in a city. That way you lessen the risk of update conflicts, and ever-growing documents as your application scales.

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc && doc.city) {
      emit(doc.city, null);
  }
}
```

The general advice is: small docs, immutable models. See https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/11/21/Best-and-Worst-Practices.html